# Extensions in Flutter Dart for Static Methods

Tags: flutter, dart

I created an extension method of the Navigator class as shown below:

```
extension on Navigator {

  static void navigatorToLoginPage(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => 
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => LoginViewModel(), 
        child: LoginPage()
      )
    ));
  }

}
```

Now, I am having problems calling it from another file.

Inside the build function of another widget, I tried calling the Navigator.navigateToLoginPage but it does not recognize the navigateToLoginPage as a static function.

```
  onTap: () {
                  Navigator.navigateToLoginPage(context); // this is not working. Not recognizing the navigateToLoginPage
                  _navigateToRegisterPage(context);
                }),
```

Am I missing something?

UPDATE: I was able to achieve it using the following code:

```
extension AppNavigator on Navigator {

  static void navigateToLoginPage(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => 
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => LoginViewModel(), 
        child: LoginPage()
      ), fullscreenDialog: true
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it `navigatorToLoginPage`, or `navigateToLoginPage`?  You've got both.